# Apache Pulsar: Error Checking/Getting Partition Metadata while creating producer

Tags: node.js, apache-pulsar, pulsar

When attempting to create a topic on Apache Pulsar during testing using Node.js, the following errors occurred:

```
[[::1]:53665 -> [::1]:6650] Failed partition-metadata lookup req_id: 10 error: Retryable msg: org.apache.pulsar.client.api.PulsarClientException: Connection already closed
Error encountered while checking/getting partition metadata when creating a producer on persistent://public/default/payment-topic -- TimeOut

[[::1]:53665 -> [::1]:6650] Read operation failed: Bad file descriptor
Even after several retries, the topic creation remains unsuccessful, and the error message "Failed to create producer: TimeOut" persists.
```

The following is my code:

```
            import { AuthenticationToken, Client, LogLevel } from 'pulsar-client';

            const paymentPulsarClient = new Client({
                serviceUrl: 'pulsar://localhost:6650',
                authentication: new AuthenticationToken({
                    token: 'xxxxx',
                })
            });
            const producer = await paymentPulsarClient.createProducer({
                topic: 'payment-topic',
                sendTimeoutMs: 30_000,
                batchingEnabled: true,
            });
```